# Firefox flex and max-width

Tags: css, image, firefox, flexbox

I’m trying to display an image centered and resized by CSS (`max-width` / `max-height`, `flex`).

This is working fine in Chrome but not in Firefox. What’s wrong?

```css
a {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 5px;
}
img { 
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<a class="frame">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/500x150"/>
</a>
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/ymLb50w0/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution...

```
      a {
         border: 1px solid red;
         display: inline-block; 
          height: 100px;
          width: 100px;
         justify-content: center;
         align-items: center;
         box-sizing: border-box;
          padding: 5px; 
        max-width: 100%;
      }
      img {    
         max-width: 100%;
         max-height: 100%;
         border: 1px solid green;
       }


    <body style="text-align: center;">
        <a class="frame">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/500x150"/>
        </a>
    </body>
```

Comment: If I use `inline-block`, picture is not vertically centered anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to align it vertically like it's explained [here](http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/)

Horizontal alignment shouldn't be a problem